# How to import styles in a project after publishing a component library as npm package?

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, tailwind-css, vercel

If i use `npm link`, then adding `node_modules/{component-library}/src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}` in tailwind.config.js works locally. but styles again disappear when my project is deployed to vercel.

I want an alternative to this solution, which can work on vercel deployements too, because i dont think pointing to a file inside node_modules is a good idea.

I tried

- adding `node_modules/{component-library}/src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}` to `tailwind.config.js`.
- import globals.css or tailwind.css in index.ts of component library -> this led to all my **project ** classes and colours getting overridden by library's. For eg., colour primary was pointing to library's primary shade instead of my prjects'.